# ListView Parsing Persian, Greek, Arabic or UTF-8 xml

Tags: android, listview, xml-parsing

I used a [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) about listview parsing xm from internet and using LasyAdapter shows the items in listview. When I add persian characters in xml (into one of childnodes) the result is some boxes in listview (after showing the text in listview). The format of xml is UTF-8, too. I used typeface too (but didn't work). Besides when I type Pwesian into the application it shows alright but it can't show Persiann content parsed from xml. Thanks in advance. I updated the post with original XMLparser (which was the problem).

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find the answer. Thanks from @Serdak. He made me think of reader. In getXMLFromUrl part I should have changed:
 `xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);` to `xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");`
 and in getDomElement part I should change:
`InputSource is = new InputSource(); is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));` to `InputSource is = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));` 
Please note that "url" and "xml" are both Strings which are called by main activity and are used in XMLparser.jave (which contains both getXmlFromUrl() and getDomElement() ). 
These commands are in main activity:
`XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL)
;Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);` 
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The reader that you use to read the Xml values is probably not set to UTF-8 and that's why causing encoding problem.

Try using your reader with an encoding option like this.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Hello dear. I think you are right. But I don't know where to put this line in? Should I put it in XMLParser.java in `InputSource is = new InputSource(); is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));` ? This is a part of document builder. I should mention when I changed the method to SAX parser there was no problem. In SAX parser I had: `DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());`

Comment: I can't use BufferedReader because My url is defined as String I mean url in `String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url);` is String type. I tried to change it to URL but XMLparser.java didn't respond correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The **StringReader** Object would make an exception when the XML string contains **Unicode** characters such as **Persian** letters. So please pass the **InputStream** object to the **Document** object straightly

Thank you