# Parse Json text as question mark

Tags: android, json, mysqli, android-sqlite

I'm using Json for getting text from sql database.

There are many Unicode formats like UTF-8 for saving data in database.

I used UTF-8 for saving text. Text is not English. It is Persian or Arabic. But Json shows text as `????`. I think the problem is from Json Parser. Please help.

```
  public class JSONParser {

      static InputStream is = null;
      static JSONObject jObj = null;
      static String json = "";

      // constructor
      public JSONParser() {

      }

      // function get json from url
      // by making HTTP POST or GET method
      public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
          List < NameValuePair > params) {

          // Making HTTP request
          try {

              // check for request method
              if (method == "POST") {
                  // request method is POST
                  // defaultHttpClient
                  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                  httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

                  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                  is = httpEntity.getContent();

              } else if (method == "GET") {
                  // request method is GET
                  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                  url += "?" + paramString;
                  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                  is = httpEntity.getContent();
              }


          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          try {
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  is, "UTF-8"), 8);
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
              }
              is.close();
              json = sb.toString();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
          }

          // try parse the string to a JSON object
          try {
              jObj = new JSONObject(json);
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
          }

          // return JSON String
          return jObj;

      }
  }
```

I think the problem is not from android. Because when I access the php file straightly from browser, it shows Arabic as `????`. I'm sure my database is UTF-8_general_ci The php is like below:

```
    <?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once(__ROOT__.'/Appstore/db_connect.php'); 

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$total = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM Apps") or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($total);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM Apps limit 0,10") or die(mysql_error());


// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["products"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $product["name"] = $row["name"];
    $product["rate"] = $row["rate"];
    $product["short_description"] = $row["short_description"];
    $product["size"] = $row["size"];
    $product["thumb_url"] = $row["thumb_url"];

    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["products"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: you say you're storing the text in the db using utf-8, but then use iso8859 in your bufferedreader? That's going to totally mangle the utf text.

Comment: I checked `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);` too. But it doesn't work.

Comment: I used `UTF-8_general_ci` and `UTF-8_unicode_ci` in database. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @NamikazeMinato did you get solutions for this? I am facing this issue as of 2020 ))

Comment: @AzizjonKholmatov Yes. please take a look at my other question. I answered it there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660235/listview-parsing-persian-greek-arabic-or-utf-8-xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `cp1256_general_ci` instead of `UTF-8_general_ci` in your database.. and also us it as collation for the fields too.